# ManyToOne Association with cloned Entity is not updated on flush

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

** **Updated Question** **

It's strange, we have an `Entity` which defines a simple association:

```
/**
 *
 * @var MyParent
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyParent", inversedBy="parents")
 */
private $myParent;
```

`MyParent` looks like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity", mappedBy="myParent")
 */
private $parents;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->parents = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function __clone() {
    $this->id = null;
}
```

Now we call the entity by e.g.

```
$entity = $repository->find(1);
```

and get an entity which has myParent set.

Now we create a new Parent by cloning it and set it to the loaded entity:

```
$newParent = clone $someOtherMyParent();
$this->em->persist($newParent);
$entity->setParent($newParent);
$this->em->persist($entity);
$this->em->flush();
```

But the new parent won't be saved with entity, nothing happens, no error, it simply fails silently.

Using

```
$newEntity = new MyParent(); //instead of clone $someOtherMyParent
```

is working as expected.

We are sure to update the owning side here. What is happening?

Comment: Do you add child `Entity` to `MyParent` inside `setParent`?

Comment: no, but why should that be necessary as we're updating the `owning side` here already?

Comment: You're probably right here. But I would give it a try. ;-)

Comment: tried - and as expected it did not change anything :-(

Comment: found it! will update question and provide an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that one has to reset the collection as well if you clone `MyParent` because otherwise Doctrine doesn't recognize the new target obviously:

```
public function __clone() {
    $this->id = null;
    $this->parents = new ArrayCollection(); // this fixes the issue!
}
```

If someone could explain why this is happening in the comments, it'd be very happy to know.